# git clone as part of automatic configuration of EC2 instance?

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, gitlab

I am setting up an EC2 instance with Terraform, and I need to run a large script during this process. I want to download the script from our gitlab repository with something like:

```
git clone git@gitlab.something.org:a_name/project.git
Cloning into 'project'...
The authenticity of host 'gitlab.something.org (12.34.56.78)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:....
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Cloning into ...
```

When I run this from the command line, I have to confirm, but this isn't possible in my situation.

However in `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log` I see this (after having uploaded the correct, private key):

```
Cloning into 'project'...
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I am hoping this error is simply the result of not responding with a 'yes' - is there a way to tell git that it's OK, I know what I am doing, and just get on with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use your automated system to deploy a `known_hosts` file which has the correct hostkeys. You can copy the entries from your own known_hosts, e.g. using `ssh-keygen -F gitlab.something.org` *(this works even if the file has been hashed)*.

The file could be deployed either at `~/.ssh/known_hosts` or at `/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts`.

Note that the hostkey verification **isn't** there just to make you confirm what you're doing; it's there to confirm that what you're trying to do matches with what is actually happening. Much like HTTPS, it's meant to guard against external factors such as MITM attacks – the URL you've entered might be 100% correct the whole time, but the packets might suddenly get rerouted to the wrong server months or years later.

Comment: I understand - however, in this particular situation I'm creating an EC2 instance about once a month, that will download a script, run it to test a database backup by restoring it, and then the instance is destroyed. I think it is probably going to be safe enough, but I do appreciate the security concerns. I tried to run ssh-keyscan as part of the user_data, but it doesn't seem to get run at all.

Comment: You don't need to automate running ssh-keyscan at all. Just deploy a static one-line file that contains your GitLab server's public key.

Comment: That works fine - only problem now is that git apparently fails automatically simply because it is not running on a tty, but that is another problem. Thanks!